# Cannot resolve symbol AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, android-studio, android-async-http

I'm trying to use:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

and it says:

> cannot resolve symbol 'AsyncHttpClient'.

I'm using latest Android Studio and build.gradle min:15 target:22

Comment: There is nothing named `AsyncHttpClient` in Android. If you are are using [this library](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), make sure that your dependency is set up properly and that you have added the appropriate `import` statement.

Comment: @CommonsWare It doesn't find anything to import (like alt+enter) so it doesn't understand anything. what do you mean there is nothing named  AsyncHttpClient? and where can I see the dependency? or how can I use it anyway?

Comment: "what do you mean there is nothing named AsyncHttpClient?" -- I mean just what I wrote. There is nothing in [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) named `AsyncHttpClient`.

Comment: I know English. you say there is nothing and then you send me the link of AsyncHttpClient and you told me to check my imports. You confused me by saying at last that there is a way to do what I need. That's what I need.

Comment: anyway it seems I found the way installing and importing the library. i initially thought that it was a build-in library. and when someone especially new to this like me asks something its good to give a nice answer not just repeating yourselves. just saying. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @STRATOSpeed The first comment succinctly describes exactly the solution you ended up with.  If you don't understand an answer, say so.  Don't just assume it's bogus because you don't understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

download jar file from http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ and paste in in app/lib folder

Add maven dependency using Gradle buildscript in format

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

and then Import the http package.

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
```